# Illustrator: Edit text in multiple text boxes at the same time

Tags: adobe-illustrator, typography, text, illustrator-scripting, data-merge

I have two text boxes that I need to have identical text, but in different fonts. Is there any way I can edit only the text content of both at the same time (keeping the fonts different).

Answer (score 5):

You can dynamically load text into Illustrator using an XML file.

> Using the Variables panel, you can import an XML file and use that to
>   control the existence of objects, what images appear in linked image
>   containers, and what text appears in a text frame. You can also
>   control the data that appears in a graph. The typical workflow is to
>   create a template document and then tag it for variables.

There are multiple tutorials online discussing how to do this. This article: [HOW TO USE ADOBE ILLUSTRATOR VARIABLE DATA WITH XML](http://hypertransitory.com/blog/2014/05/27/use-adobe-illustrator-variable-data-xml/) has a good video and step by step tutorial on how to do this.

Or you can do either of the following:

1) Delete the second text box. Make the text change. Copy -> paste text and apply the font or character style.

or

2) Just copy the text and paste into the other text box after finishing editing the first text box.

Comment: Great, will try out the first option. I've been changing text manually but would be good to automate it somehow. Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

You can use this short little snippet of a script:

```
#target illustrator
function ChangeTextContents(){
    if(app.documents.length > 0 && app.documents[0].selection != null){
        var newText = prompt("Enter new text:", "");
        if(newText != null){
            var sel = app.activeDocument.selection;
            for(var i=0; i<sel.length; i++){
                var s = sel[i];
                if(s.typename == "TextFrame"){
                    s.contents = newText;
                }
            };
        }
    }
}
ChangeTextContents();
```

It will simply put your input text into the text frames that you will need to have in a selection.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a modification that allows you to select groups and it changes the text within those groups. This works on nested levels (groups within groups) or on selected text layers directly.

```
#target illustrator
function ChangeTextContents(){
    if(app.documents.length > 0 && app.documents[0].selection != null){
        var newText = prompt("Enter new text:", "");
        if(newText != null){
            var sel = app.activeDocument.selection;
            for(var i=0; i < sel.length; i++){
                ChangeElement(sel[i],newText);
            }
        }
    }
}

function ChangeElement(thisSelection,text) {
                // For each selected item, determine if it is text or a group
                // For text items, just change the contents
                if(thisSelection.typename == "TextFrame"){
                    thisSelection.contents = text;
                    // For group items, iterate through each group item and recursive call this function. 
                } else if (thisSelection.typename == "GroupItem") {
                    // Change the text items within this level of the group
                    for(var k=0; k < thisSelection.textFrames.length; k++){
                        ChangeElement(thisSelection.textFrames[k],text);
                    }

                    // Now recursively process the group items within this group
                    for(var j=0; j < thisSelection.groupItems.length; j++){
                        ChangeElement(thisSelection.groupItems[j],text);
                    }
                }
}

ChangeTextContents();
```

Comment: Hello Rik, welcome to GD.SE and thanks for your answer! Please have a look at the [tour](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/tour) and the [help] to get an idea of how Stack Exchange works--we're not just a random forum. Once your reputation reaches 20, you're also more than welcome to join us in [chat]. Keep contributing and enjoy the site!